# SharePoint 2013 Foundation Full Crawl LOB Errors

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to get the crawl to work on SharePoint but the full crawls never stops and when I stop it the crawl log has below.

```
topicpages://
Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: 
Microsoft.BusinessData.Infrastructure.BdcException The shim execution failed 
unexpectedly - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..: 
System.Net.WebException The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. )
```

I have been searching the net continuously and made sure the folders have the correct permissions etc

The longest I let the search go is 100 hours

Using:

Sharepoint 2013 Foundation

Server 2008 R2

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas what to try and get this going correctly?

Comment: Can you post your content sources configuration (list of urls)?

Comment: Hi have the below

Start Address: http://intranet.<company name>.co.nz

Crawl everything under hostname for each start address
Enable incremental crawls

Comment: Maybe this url is not present in alternate access mappings?